# Request works in python but doesn't in C#

Tags: c#, httprequest, restsharp

I have the following GET request in python:

```
  url = "https://web.trf3.jus.br/certidao/Certidao/Solicitar"

  payload={}
  headers = {
    'authority': 'web.trf3.jus.br',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt-PT;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
  }

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

It works fine. However, when I try to do the same request in C# using RestSharp, I always get timeout errors. The request never completes successfully.

```
var request = new RestRequest("https://web.trf3.jus.br/certidao/Certidao/Solicitar", Method.Get);
request.AddHeader("authority", "web.trf3.jus.br");
request.AddHeader("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
request.AddHeader("accept-language", "pt-BR,pt-PT;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "max-age=0");
request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua", "\"Chromium\";v=\"104\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"104\"");
request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-dest", "document");
request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-mode", "navigate");
request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-site", "none");
request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-user", "?1");
request.AddHeader("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
```

Comment: Use a network monitoring tool such as Fiddler or Wireshark to inspect the actual HTTP request send in both situations. Hopefully you'll be able to identify a difference.

Comment: Can you please show how how you make the request in the c# version?

Comment: You need to show the code where you actually call the request, this isn't enough code to diagnose.

Comment: The C# code in the sample never sends the request. You need to call GetResponse()

Comment: @DavidG I ommited the .Execute() of restsharp just because, didn't think it would cause the question to be unanswerable. What happens is that the Execute() method hangs for almost like a minute and I get timeout error. It is working with Flurl as suggested in the other answer. IDK why restsharp can't make this request. Didn't succeed with wireshark or fiddler debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it does not answer the question why, the following works well using Flurl, which is my personal preference for http calls:

```
using Flurl.Http;

namespace Program
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var url = "https://web.trf3.jus.br/certidao/Certidao/Solicitar";

            var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            headers.Add("authority", "web.trf3.jus.br");
            headers.Add("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
            headers.Add("accept-language", "pt-BR,pt-PT;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6");
            headers.Add("cache-control", "max-age=0");
            headers.Add("sec-ch-ua", "\"Chromium\";v=\"104\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"104\"");
            headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
            headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
            headers.Add("sec-fetch-dest", "document");
            headers.Add("sec-fetch-mode", "navigate");
            headers.Add("sec-fetch-site", "none");
            headers.Add("sec-fetch-user", "?1");
            headers.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");
            headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");

            var result = await url.WithHeaders(headers).GetStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This works too using RestSharp (have you forgotten await by any chance?)

```
using Flurl.Http;
using RestSharp;

namespace Program
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var url = "https://web.trf3.jus.br/certidao/Certidao/Solicitar";

            var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "authority", "web.trf3.jus.br" },
                { "accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" },
                { "accept-language", "pt-BR,pt-PT;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6" },
                { "cache-control", "max-age=0" },
                { "sec-ch-ua", "\"Chromium\";v=\"104\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"104\"" },
                { "sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0" },
                { "sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"" },
                { "sec-fetch-dest", "document" },
                { "sec-fetch-mode", "navigate" },
                { "sec-fetch-site", "none" },
                { "sec-fetch-user", "?1" },
                { "upgrade-insecure-requests", "1" },
                { "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" }
            };

            var client = new RestClient();

            var request = new RestRequest(url,Method.Get);
            request.AddHeaders(headers);

            var result = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this package. It works here too. I was trying with wireshark and fiddler to find out what was happening with RestSharp. I may just stop using it or just use Flurl for this request only. Thanks for your help

Comment: check out RestSharp code in my answer as well

Comment: Now I'm more lost that I was in the beginning. Now the request in restsharp is working. Both your method passing the headers as a dictionary and my initial try. No idea what is going on here. I had deployed my applicatin to AWS and it was also failing there. I may stick with Flurl in prod environment to prevent errors. The only thing I can think about is some DNS error that caused the request to be sent the first time. Now that Flurl made it, maybe it got cached? No clue

Comment: Might be something to do with the way you call Execute - you seem to have been using sync methods while mine are async

Comment: It didnt matter, even with sync or async it wouldn't complete. Always timeout errors.